# Write a Perl script that lists the directory contents of a directory specified by the user

Tags: perl

I have tried this code but it doesnt work for the user-input directory.
It only lists the PWD.
Help!

```
#script to list the directory contents of a user specified directory

system("pwd");
print "enter the path of your d1rectory\n";
$path =<STDIN>;
system(" cd Spath");
#system ("chdir $path");
system("ls");
```

[image: My code screenshot]

Comment: unfortunately had to post a screenshot as the linux terminal wasnt copying.

Comment: [Video tutorial to copy and paste from a putty terminal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9jgQLfy4Es)

Comment: Added the code as text. Shame to let my newly-acquired `tesseract` knowledge go to waste :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already @toolic mentioned in a comment you have to make `system "ls $path"`

But you are already in Perl, you can use you the Perl Inbuilt functions like [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) or [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/functions/opendir.html). for example

```
my $s = <STDIN>;
chomp $s;
$s .= '/' if length($s);
while(my $file = glob("\Q$s\E*")){

    print $file,"\n";
}
```

Comment: They should also be used `Cwd` to `getcwd()` instead of `system( "pwd" );` `Cwd` is a standard module and is installed with Perl. A list of standard modules is in `perldoc perlmodlib`.

Comment: Your substitution might be more readable if you chose a different delimiter. `$s =~ s|(?<!/)$|/|igs`

Comment: `glob` [has quite a few caveats](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1206848), especially when used with a variable pattern.

Comment: `glob($s."*")` should be `glob("\Q$s\E*")`

Comment: `$s=~s/(?<!\/)$/\//igs;` can be replaced with `$s .= '/' if length($s);`. Doesn't matter if it get duplicated, and you shouldn't add `/` to an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

A Unix process has something called an "environment" associated with it. The environment contains details of how the process is being run. One of the elements of the environment, for example, is the current working directory.

When a process starts another process, the new, child process inherits a copy of the environment from the parent process. The child process can change anything it wants in its copy of the environment, but it cannot change the parent's copy of the environment (or, at least, not easily).

Your code involves four processes. In call to `system()` creates a new process, with a new copy of the environment. When each call to `system()` exits, its environment ceases to exist.

1. Your program is the first process. It inherits a copy of the environment of the shell process that starts it. This environment has a current working directory.
2. The first call to `system()` creates a new process and gives it a copy of the main program's environment. That subprocess runs `pwd` and exits. Its copy of the environment disappears.
3. The next call to `system()` creates another new process and gives it a new copy of the main program's environment. That subprocess changes its current working directory - but only for its copy of the environment. When the call to `system()` exits, that copy of the environment (with its changed current working directory) ceases to exist).
4. The final call to `system()` creates another new process and gives it a new copy of the main program's environment (which still has the original program's current working directory). That process calls `ls` on its current directory and then exits - removing its environment in the process.

So, effectively, your call to `cd` does nothing as it changes the directory in an environment that immediately ceases to exist.

The quick fix (as you have been shown) is to just pass the `$path` variable to `ls`.

The correct fix (as you have also been shown) is to not use subprocesses to do this and to use, instead, Perl's built-in tools.

When I see questions like this, I have to wonder what they are teaching on computing courses these days :-)